# JTable select and deselect not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem with my JTable. Firstly I selected some entries in my table. However when I deselect some of them, the table could not understand it.

Example scenario: I select job1 and 2 for the testing after that I change my mind and  de-select job2. But in the result I saw job1 job1 and job2 ( job 1 seen 2 times and even though I dis-select job 2 I saw them.) Or after selected all the jobs ( choose all button) I want to deselect all of them (Clear button) when I click clear all the table seems empty. It is good but somehow the background of the program still protect the all old selection. How can I solve this?

Try:

I created the row of my table by read csv file.

```
public class JobSelectionListPanel extends JPanel {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5198916547962359735L;

  private static JobSelectionListPanel INSTANCE = new JobSelectionListPanel();

  public static JobSelectionListPanel getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  private JTable table;
  private JButton next, back, btnClear, btnNewButton, btnChooseAll;
  private JobList fnnJobList = new JobList();

  private JobSelectionListPanel() {

    table = new JTable();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setBorder(new CompoundBorder());

    // Read all FNN jobs from file
    try {
      fnnJobList.readFromFile("rules.csv");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      System.out.println("You are not able to read the rules.csv file");
    }

    // Create ArrayList of JobNames



      Object[][] initialData = new Object[fnnJobList.size()][1];

        int i = 0;
        for (Job jobDes : fnnJobList) {
          initialData[i][0] = (Object) jobDes.getJobname();
          i++;
        }

        String[] columnNames = new String[] { "", "Your preferences" };
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(initialData, columnNames) {

          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
          @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
          Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] { Object.class, Boolean.class };

          @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
          public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return columnTypes[columnIndex];
          }
        });

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(80);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(40);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

I user want to choose all rows then I implemented this.
btnChooseAll = new JButton("Choose all");

```
btnChooseAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    DefaultTableModel chooseAllData = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    if (DeviceGroups.DeviceAList.size() == 0 || DeviceGroups.DeviceBList.size() == 0
        || DeviceGroups.DeviceCList.size() == 0 || DeviceGroups.DeviceDList.size() == 0)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
          "You should choose at least 1 device for each test device to apply this test case", "Invalid OPTION",
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < chooseAllData.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < chooseAllData.getColumnCount(); j++) {
          chooseAllData.setValueAt(true, i, j);

        }
      }

  }
});
```

For clear all preferences :

```
 btnClear = new JButton("Clear all");
    // Clear button create a model of JTable and delete all the rows of table!!
    btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        DefaultTableModel clearTableData = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < clearTableData.getRowCount(); i++) {
          for (int j = 1; j < clearTableData.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            clearTableData.setValueAt(null, i, j);

          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the following problem in your code: mixing up view indexes and model indexes. This is the offending snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    if (table.getValueAt(i, 1) != null) {
        if (((Boolean) table.getValueAt(i, 1)).booleanValue()) {
          String jobName = (((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
```

You are using the `i` variable to denote view row indices, since you are checking values in this statement: `table.getValueAt(i, 1) != null`.

But then a bit further you are using `i` to index the model:

```
String jobName = ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
```

If `i` is to be a view index, you need to convert it to a model index before indexing the model:

```
 String jobName = ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(i), 0).toString();
```

---

Also, when columns would be switched around in the view (ie on screen in your GUI), the following will probably not work as intended:

```
table.getValueAt(i, 1) != null
```

You most likely mean to say, get the second column value in the model, not the view. Best rewrite then as

```
table.getValueAt(i, table.convertColumnIndexToView(1)) != null
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it did not solve my problem . I edited my question please check the image that I added. I deselected WAF5-H but still the table saved it also doubled the other selection called WAF5-T. After deselected I expected to see only WAF5-T one time in the information message.

Comment: @limonik That's all good and well, but you didn't post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): a **Minimal**, **Complete**, and **Verifiable Example**. The code that shows the error text doesn't appear in your code snippets! Nowhere in the code snippets is there anything related to selection! I can only look at the snippet you posted and go from there.

Comment: @limonik `Object[][] initialData = new Object[fnnJobList.size()][1];` ... shouldn't that be `Object[][] initialData = new Object[fnnJobList.size()][2];`? And shouldn't you be initializing the second columnn with `Boolean.FALSE`?

Comment: @limonik Also `clearTableData.setValueAt(null, i, j);`, why not do `clearTableData.setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, i, j);`?